# Any way to make 3DS Powersave work on Ubuntu (Wily)/Wine?

Tags: wine, games

Before moving to Ubuntu from Windows, I used to use Powersaves quite frequently to modify and back up my save files from my 3DS.

The software is small and is said to be able to actually run on Wine but, sadly, will not detect the USB ports, something that's necessary as it rewrites save files on a physical level on the cartridge.

Is there any way to make the software work on Ubuntu/make Wine detect USB ports?

Software is;
https://powersaves3ds.maximummemory.com/

Answer (score 0):

Something you can try is running it in a Virtualbox virtual machine, with a version of Windows, and then giving it access to a USB port. It's pretty low level, so I have my doubts, but I think it's worth a shot.